# How to setup build.sbt with sbt-assembly plugin?

Tags: java, scala, sbt

Posting this only because no other suggested solutions helped. 
I have a very simple one-class Scala sbt project which needs to be a runnable .jar file. It has some java dependencies so `sbt package` won't work for me, I need a fat jar. The project has the following structure.

```
├── build.sbt
├── project
│   ├── assembly.sbt
│   ├── build.properties
│   ├── project
│   └── target
├── README.md
├── src
│   ├── main
│   └── test
├── target
│   ├── scala-2.12
│   ├── specs2-reports
│   ├── streams
│   └── test-reports
```

It has one main class and one test spec. In order to make sbt generate a fat jar I added `assembly.sbt` into `project` dir and modified my `build.sbt` accordingly.

```
import AssemblyKeys._

name := "myproj"

version := "1.0"

scalaVersion := "2.12.8"

libraryDependencies ++= Seq(
  "au.com.bytecode" %% "opencsv" % "2.4",
  "org.specs2" %% "specs2-core" % "4.3.0" % "test"
)

scalacOptions in Test ++= Seq("-Yrangepos")

assemblyMergeStrategy in assembly := {
  case PathList("META-INF", xs @ _*) => MergeStrategy.discard
  case x => MergeStrategy.first
}
```

However,`import AssemblyKeys._` is red with `cannot resolve symbol`? Trying it from console gives me

```
import AssemblyKeys._
       ^
[error] Type error in expression
Project loading failed: (r)etry, (q)uit, (l)ast, or (i)gnore?
```

What else have I forgotten because assebly github page does not state that we need to do anything else. My sbt version is `sbt 1:1.2.8-1`.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Under your `project` directory, you need to add a `plugins.sbt` file which has the following included:

```
addSbtPlugin("com.eed3si9n" % "sbt-assembly" % "0.15.0")
```

Then, delete `AssemblyKeys._` and refresh sbt. Only after a successful refresh you'll be able to insert that import

Comment: Once I did this and tried to run `compile` in sbt console I got unresolved `opencsv` dependency exception.  I then closed idea completely and also removed `~/.sbt/0.13` dir and tried again. sbt assembly successfully worked!

Comment: @minerals Yeah sometimes caching goes bananas, although if you're on sbt 1.2.8, everything should be under the ~/.sbt/1.0 directory if I recall correctly.

Comment: It should. But I also had `0.13` there for some reason and thought that it might conflict with `1.0`. Regarding Idea IDE, I think it does not work well with sbt at all :(